# python reverse function and boolean values error

Tags: python, boolean, reverse

i have written a function that produces a tuple of two lists from one list. one list contains the second, fourth and fifth values and the other list contains all the remaining values. i also have a condition that if reverse=True the values of the lists will be reversed when returned.

```
def seperate(x, reverse=False):

    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
            xs.append(x[i])
            ys.append(x[i + 1])
    return (xs, ys)
    if reverse is True:
            x = xs.reverse()
            y = ys.reverse()
    return(x, y)
```

for some reason when reverse is True the lists are not being reversed, they are the same as when reverse is False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `reverse = True` is not working is that you have a `return` statement right before the check:

```
return (xs, ys)
```

The code after the `return` statement is never executed.

Additionally, `reverse()` reverses the list in place and returns `None`, so `x` and `y` will end up being `None`.

Here is how both issues can be fixed:

```
if reverse:
        xs.reverse()
        ys.reverse()
return (xs, ys)
```

Finally, you could use slicing instead of an explicit loop to extract the odd/even elements:

```
In [7]: x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [8]: x[::2]
Out[8]: [1, 3, 5, 7]

In [9]: x[1::2]
Out[9]: [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

`reverse()` does not return any value. It reverses the list in place. So the reversed list is in `xs` and in `ys`.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_reverse.htm

Also you are returning before you execute the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (xs, ys)
if reverse is True:
```

In functions, after `return` everything is not working. That's why your `if` statement is not working. It's making everything ineffective after `return`. You can imagine it like;

```
def wr():
    x="hey"
    y="Hello"
    return x
    return y
print (wr())
```

Like this one, this function going to write only `hey`, because it returned one time and other `return y` is ineffective anymore.